# Extension Method for Interface in Internal Class

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, dynamic-linq, internal-class

I am currently trying to write extensions to [Dynamic Linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/). For that I need to add a method signature to the `IEnumerableSignatures` interface located in the internal class `ExpressionParser`.

```
internal class ExpressionParser
{
    interface IEnumerableSignatures
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

While I could add the signature to the code directly, I'd rather define this as an extension method to the interface, to keep the original code clean. Usually, to add the method `DefaultIfEmpty`, I would do something like this:

```
internal static class Extension 
{
    static void DefaultIfEmpty(this ExpressionParser.IEnumerableSignatures sig);
}
```

This gives an access error though, because `ExpressionParser` is internal. I have already tried with several combinations of access level for the class and method.

Is there a way to add an extension method to such an interface or do I have to mess with the original code?

**[edit]** Turns out that, even when making the interface itself internal (or public for that matter), it is not recognized by dynamic linq. I still got some not-found exception on runtime. So there's no (obvious) way around editing the codeplex code. **[/edit]**

Comment: Is it within the same assembly?

Comment: If it has to be. At first I wanted to the dll from codeplex, but as I added my code directly to the source code, yes, it currently is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not do that since `IEnumerableSignatures` is a private interface (it has no access modifier and the default one is `private`) and there is no way to access it from outside of `ExpressionParser` class.

But if you can change the interface access modifier then there should be no problem if you assign the access modifiers correct.

```
internal static class Extension
{
    internal static int Foo(this ExpressionParser.IEnumerableSignatures b)
    {
        return b.Ib;
    }
}

internal class ExpressionParser
{
    public int Ia { get; set; }
    internal interface IEnumerableSignatures
    {
        int Ib { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You can not hide your safe (private/less accessible/inner class) inside your house (outer class) if you give the key to someone.

You can not use a less accessible class in a class with higher accessibility. For example using a private class in a public one. You can not make a public extension method for a class that is internal because you can not use the public extension method outside the assembly because you can not access the internal class from outside of assembly!

Comment: I already suspected something like this. I don't need access to `DefaultIfEmpty` directly, I just wanted to add the method signature in a place that is easier to maintain in case of updates to the code from codeplex.

Answer (score 1):

Both the interface `IEnumerableSignatures` and the method `DefaultIfEmpty` are `private`. If you make them `internal` (or `public`) it will work.

```
internal class ExpressionParser
{
   internal interface IEnumerableSignatures { }
}

internal static class Extension
{
    internal static void DefaultIfEmpty(this ExpressionParser.IEnumerableSignatures sig) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It will of course never work if `ExpressionParser` and `Extension` are in different assemblies, because they are both `internal`.

Comment: 'Never' is a strong word. There is still the option to define a Friend assembly.

Comment: It is in the same assembly (currently). But that modification won't help me really. If I have to modify the source code of the class anyway, I could also add the signature directly ;)

Comment: @bone-idle The interface is `private`, so it won't be visible anywhere but inside the `ExpressionParser` class. You cannot write an extension method for something you cannot see. (The `Extension` class doesn't know `ExpressionParser.IEnumerableSignatures` exists)

Answer (score 1):

No access modifier is the same as private, so just add internal to the inter face

```
internal class ExpressionParser 
{
    internal interface IEnumerableSignatures
    {
    }
}
internal static class Extension
{
    static void DefaultIfEmpty(this ExpressionParser.IEnumerableSignatures sig)
    {

    }
}
```

And it should work

Comment: That won't help me really. If I have to modify the source code of the class anyway, I could also add the signature directly ;)